# Moving chained Planning Entities while solving time

Tags: java, optaplanner, constraint-programming, drools-planner

In Optaplanner, is it possible to assign the same planning variable to different planning entities in a move (between score calculations)? For eg, when Customer A is assigned to a StandStill, Customer B will also be assigned to the same StandStill.
Appreciated for any ideas or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generic moves, you would be able to do this with a mimic value selector (see docs "mimic selection"), but it doesn't exist yet. Feel free to create a jira: OptaPlanner should support it in the future.

Meanwhile, you can do it with a custom Move, see docs "Customer MoveListFactory/MoveIteratorFactory".